# Will installing Xubuntu wipe the whole HDD?

Tags: system-installation, windows, xubuntu

I'm new to Linux and I've been trialing Xubuntu 14.04 via USB Flash. I'm about ready to install it on to an older computer (X86, 32bit, 1.28Gb RAM, Intel 'Celeron' 2.3Mhz CPU, 80Gb HDD). My question is in three parts:

(1) I understand from articles on this site that Xubuntu will overwrite the existing OS (XP) but I want to make certain that it will overwrite the existing partitions whilst installing, or will I need to format the HDD first for a clean install?

(2) With the future intention of increasing the RAM to its system maximum of 4Gb, should I make the swap partition, at install, 4.5Gb? Most of my software usage is CAD, photo-editing, office work and internet browsing.

(3) And finally, should I choose the 'encrypt LVM' option on install, just to be on the safe side of paranoid?

In anticipation of any responses, many thanks; and could you please, please, keep any responses clear and simple, because I am not computer savvy... Although I'm always willing to learn. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Installing Xubuntu Alongside Windows

No. Xubuntu WILL NOT OVERWRITE Windows when you choose the appropriate option.

When you reach this screen (see below), select `Install Xubuntu Alongside [OS]`.
[image]

### Should I Add/Use Swap?

Since you mentioned CAD, I would suggest you add `4GB - 8GB` of swap, just to be on the safe side. CAD can consume a lot of memory. :)

### Should I enable LVM Encryption?

If you want to be more secure, yes. This essentially encrypts your Xubuntu installation. However, a small drawback to this encryption is that you have to remember yet another password and input it every time your machine boots.

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a quick response Norman Li, although I'm not sure about your answer to my first question. My intention is to get rid of XP from my desktop, hence the point about overwriting or to format HDD to achieve a clean install.

Comment: No problem! Anytime! :)

Comment: Also, just for future notice, you should mark the answer that works as "Accepted", just in case someone else has the same problem and comes searching. :)